# emacs print command output

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a series of system calls using this syntax:

```
(call-process "/bin/sh" nil nil t "-c" command)
```

where `command` is the shell command. I wonder if there is a way to print the output when I have these system calls in an `commands.el` file and I call it with `emacs --script commands.el`. Currently, the commands are executed but all of the output appears to be captured and not printed.

Comment: The output is normally collected in the current buffer, but you have specified to have it discarded by passing `nil` as the third argument.  You can specify a different buffer through this parameter, too.

Comment: Do I have to capture it in a temporary buffer and then print the buffer? I tried `t` for the third argument but it doesn't get printed either (not sure what "current buffer" would be when ran as a script).

Comment: That sounds like a workable solution, yes.  If your session doesn't set up a buffer at any point, I'm guessing the current buffer would end up being the `*scratch*` buffer.  (Update: Confirmed.)  That one contains some comments so it's probably better to create a new, empty buffer when you start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to let emacs manage the temp buffer for you:

```
(defun run-it (cmd)
  "run CMD in shell and return result as string."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (call-process "/bin/sh" nil t t "-c" cmd)
    (buffer-string)))
```

Comment: If you want to run a shell command like this, just use the existing function shell-command-to-string. The code is almost identical (look in simple.el), but automatically uses the right shell etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, then?

```
(set-buffer (get-buffer-create " output"))
(mapc (function (lambda (cmd) (call-process "/bin/sh" nil t t "-c" cmd)))
  '("echo hello"
    "perl -e \"die qq(goodbye)\"") )
(message "%s" (buffer-string))
```

This outputs `at -e line 1.` at the end of output.  Maybe add an empty line before it, or figure out a way to suppress it.